# transition matrix in HMM Python

Tags: python

I've been using HMMpytk  (in windows OS) to develop a Hidden Markov Model. while deriving a transition matrix i get a key error. My code looks as follows:

```
hmm_model = hmm_faster.HMM()
hmm_model.set_states(['GEN' , 'NICHTGEN'])
hmm_model.set_observations(['x', 'y', 'z'])

hmm_model.randomize_matrices(seed = 10)

start_probability = {'GEN' : startToGene, 'NICHTGEN': startToNotGene}

transition_probability = {'GEN':{'geneToGene':a, 'geneToNotGene':b}, 'NICHTGEN':      {'notGeneToGene':c, 'notGeneToNotGene':d}}

hmm_model.set_initial_matrix(start_probability)
hmm_model.set_transition_matrix(transition_probability)
```

The a,b,c and d in transition_probability are variables with float values assigned to them.

The error says:

```
self.trans_matrix[self.st_list_index[st_i]][self.st_list_index[st_j]]=A_matrix[st_i][st_j]
KeyError: 'notGeneToNotGene'
```

Comment: `"notGeneToNotGene" != "notgeneToNotgene"`

Comment: sorry, it should have been "notGeneToNotGene" in both the places, have edited it now...the problem still persists